# Undefined Symbol: _ZN3a13A when importing pybind11 bindings

Tags: cmake, ipython, pybind11

I'm trying to create *pybind11* bindings for an existing *cmake* project. The `CMakeLists.txt` file looks like [the one in the tutorial](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/compiling.html#building-with-cmake). The project builds without errors, however, when trying to import the module in *ipython*, the following error comes up:

`~/workspace/a/build/pya.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3a13FooC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE`

**Trying to solve it**: It seems related to the toolchain ([this issue](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-0-4-1-undefined-symbol-at-import-of-a-cpp-extension/24420) looks similar). I've *gcc 6.5.0* and *cmake 3.12.0* installed.

Comment: It seems that you didn't properly link something. Unfortunately the names in C++ are sometimes nog very descriptive, but sometimes you recognise part of the name to give you a hint what you did not link. To be able to help you we need a minimal reproducible example here.

Comment: It seems you did not put the cpp file of the `_ZN3a13FooC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE` function to the compile command.

Comment: Additionally, check closely that the function signature in your .h file matches the one in your .cpp file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is harder to answer than necessary, the linker error message is obfuscated.  Use an [online demangler](http://demangler.com/) to see the plaintext symbol name that the linker cannot find.  Be sure to copy/paste the real mangled symbol.

A valid mangled name that somewhat resembles the error message would be `_ZN1a3FooC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE`.  Which demangles to `a::Foo::Foo(const std::string&)`.

In other words, you declared a constructor for the Foo class but forgot to write it.  Pretty standard mistake. More about these linker errors in [this Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix).